# RSS Feed Security warnings

Tags: cve

I am looking for an service to get Security Warnings (CVE) for PHP, Apache and different Frameworks.

Does someone know an source where i am able to get those as RSS Feed?

Comment: There are services, they usually cost a few thousand a year. You can monitor the ones from NIST. But those include everything, not just specific technologies.

Comment: With the use of an aggregator, you can parse the NIST feed for certain keywords: https://nvd.nist.gov/download.cfm#RSS

Comment: I did a Google search for "CVE RSS" and came up with the NIST site right away. I assume you did the same.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about information aggregation, which can go stale over time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[cvedetails.com](http://www.cvedetails.com) provides CVE feeds which can be filtered by product. Just access them from the product page.

- [PHP feed](http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-feed.php?vendor_id=74&product_id=128&version_id=0&orderby=3&cvssscoremin=0)
- [Apache feed](http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-feed.php?vendor_id=45&product_id=66&version_id=0&orderby=3&cvssscoremin=0)